# strange behavior getting count of records

Tags: ravendb

I know the fact that I can't get more than 128 records by one query and that this can be extended to 1024 if I use .Take(1024) but I have a new problem with this Code on the sample Database:

```
var albumCount = session.Query<Album>().Count();
Console.WriteLine(albumCount);          // 246 as expected?!?

var somemoredata = session.Query<Album>();
Console.WriteLine(somemoredata.Count());    // 246 but it sould be 128
int cnt = 1;
foreach (var album in somemoredata)
{
   Console.WriteLine(cnt++.ToString() + " " + album.Id);  // repeats 128 counts
}
```

How can this be? The Count of somemoredata is 246, but the foreach writes 128 Lines?!?

Where is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Take` is doing paging for you, which is part of the [**save by default**](http://ravendb.net/docs/theory/safe-by-default) principle. But `Count` should always give the actual count of the documents for that query.

This will ensure that you can:

1. Display an indication that the data shown is just a slice of the information. (Page 1 of X).
2. Let you know that we need to do paging, when you need to.

Comment: Yes, I understand this, but what I don't understand that the collection somemoredata has a Count of 246 but delivers only 128 Objects. I think this should be a real collection.Count with a value of 128.

Comment: somemoredata is `IEnumerable`. What means that it's the same as `session.Query<Album>()`. Use `.ToArray()` in order to get the fetched documents count.

Comment: That's the answer! If I can get the correct result than I'll be happy with that.